# fetching mail over http

Tags: http, email

I heard that it is possible to fetch mails or at least the number of mails from gmail accounts via http.

Is this only possible with gmail accounts?
Don't you need pop/smtp?

Would be nice if someone could explain the process in detail.

Comment: Pedantry Corner: SMTP(S) is for *sending* mails, and POP is an anemic, ancient protocol; IMAP(S) is much more useful even for programmatic access. (So: no, you don't need POP *or* SMTP for reading gmail accounts)

Answer (score 2):

GMail has an API which works over HTTP: https://code.google.com/apis/gmail/

> To use Gmail with Atom, you must already have an aggregator. Within
>   your aggregator, look for a selection titled 'Add Feed' or 'Create New
>   Channel.' Once there, enter https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom in
>   the URL field, and enter your Gmail address and password in the fields
>   provided. This will allow the aggregator to look for your new
>   messages.
>
> If you'd like to have a label view in your aggregator, just add the
>   label name to the end of the feed URL. So, to view your 'work' label
>   as a feed, it's https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/work/.
>
> Please keep in mind that Gmail messages will appear in your aggregator
>   only if there are unread messages in your inbox.

— https://code.google.com/apis/gmail/docs/inbox_feed.html